# 'ReferenceError: window is not defined' still preventing NextJS build with SSR disabled?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Recently I began transitioning my personal website from CRA to NextJS and have largely had no issues, but am a bit stuck on this error.

My site has a dynamic background that relies heavily on client-side window properties; given NextJS' SSR defaults I've isolated all references to window size in a single component, and dynamically import it with SSR disabled. I only reference the component in a single place, imported using:

> const DynamicBG = dynamic(() => import('./landingSections/FramerBG'), { 
> ssr: false, 
> })

The application behaves as expected when ran through `npm run dev` but refuses to compile through `npx next build` due to the references to client window size in my code, despite those files being imported with SSR disabled. Am I supposed to differentiate client-rendered components in some way outside dynamic importing?

Comment: Can you share the code of your component?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Resolved by moving out my component from the pages/ folder. All the components of this folder are being built my next with ssr on even if you try to disable it.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.